# How to structure real time UI instead of having lots of ajax requests in each HTML file?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core MVC and my site has a lot of CRUD pages with dynamic UI such as modals loading when click on rows on a table to display more information or load a form.

This means that all of my pages have lots of jquery ajax requests and it's starting to get messy keeping track of it all.

Is there a better way to structure this or handle real time UI with asp.net core? I would like to try and only use asp.net core but I would be open to trying some other client side frameworks but I am not sure what would be suitable.

An example of the sort of code in my html files.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentId = 1;
    var controller = "Software";
    $('tbody tr').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).children()[0].textContent;
        currentId = id;
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + "/" + controller + "/Details",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (result) {
                $('.modal-body').html(result.responseText);
            }
        })

        $('#details-modal').modal('show');
    })

    $('#details-modal').on("click", "#edit-software", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + "/" + controller + "/EditViewComponent",
            data: {
                id: currentId
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (result) {
                $('.modal-body').html(result.responseText);
            }
        })
    })

    $('#risk-icon').hover(
        function () {
            $('#risk-img').css({ "display": "block" });
        }, function () {
            $('#risk-img').css({ "display": "none" });
        })

});
```

Comment: No framework will solve architectural deficiencies. Try to make your JS method more generic and separate them by area/page/component/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using a client side (framework or) library with your jquery ajax calls here.  You can replace this with a client side framework while still using aspnet core for your api returning json just as you are today.  Structuring components and handling all the ajax calls are just a couple of the exact reasons client side frameworks have become so popular today as people demand and design more responsive UIs.  There are many to choose from. Angular, React, Vue, Knockout.  There are plenty of arguments for each one also so choosing one depends on your more specific needs.